# Error While Executing "yarn build" in next-js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, yarnpkg

I am trying to build the app to deploy it, and I am getting this error it's been a day now since I am facing this problem and I am really stuck and out of ideas and the app is working fine locally and there are no errors in developing mode, the errors appear when I execute `yarn build`

the error in the console is:

```
C:\Users\MA13\Desktop\5 days Plan\Portofolio\portfolio-frontend>yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ next build
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

./public/assets/contact.jpg
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5555:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5877:42
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)

Import trace for requested module:
./components/Contact.jsx
./pages/index.js

./public/assets/projects/property.jpg
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5555:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5877:42
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Import trace for requested module:
./components/Projects.jsx
./pages/index.js


> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

the components mentioned in the error

index:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import HomeSection from '../components/HomeSection'
import About from '../components/About'
import Skills from '../components/Skills'
import Projects from '../components/Projects'
import Contact from '../components/Contact'


export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div >
      <Head>
        <title>Mahmoud | Full Stack</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/assets/logo.png" />
      </Head>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <HomeSection/>
      <About />
      <Skills />
      <Projects />
      <Contact />
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

the projects component:

```
import Image  from 'next/image'
import Link  from 'next/Link'
import PropertyImg from '../public/assets/projects/property.jpg'

const Projects = () => {
    return (
        <div id='projects' className='w-full'>
            <div className='max-w-[1240px] mx-auto px-2 py-24 '>
                <h3 className='text-xl tracking-widest uppercase text-[#5651e5]'>Projects</h3>
                <h1>What I have Built</h1>
                <div className='grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-8 my-4'>
                    <div className='relative flex items-center justify-center w-full h-auto shadow-xl shadow-gray-400 rounded-xl p-4 group hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-[#565eef] to-[#709dff]'>
                        <Image className='rounded-xl group-hover:opacity-10' src={PropertyImg} alt='/'/>
                        <div className='hidden  group-hover:block absolute '>
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                                <div>
                                    <h3 className='text-2xl text-white tracking-wider text-center'>Property finder</h3>
                                    <p className='pb-4 pt-2 text-center text-white'>React Project</p>
                                    <Link className='group' href='/'>
                                        <p className='text-center py-3 rounded-lg text-gray-700 bg-white font-bold text-lg cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-50'>More Info</p>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='relative flex items-center justify-center w-full h-auto shadow-xl shadow-gray-400 rounded-xl p-4 group hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-[#565eef] to-[#709dff]'>
                        <Image className='rounded-xl group-hover:opacity-10' src={PropertyImg} alt='/'/>
                        <div className='hidden  group-hover:block absolute '>
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                                <div>
                                    <h3 className='text-2xl text-white tracking-wider text-center'>Property finder</h3>
                                    <p className='pb-4 pt-2 text-center text-white'>React Project</p>
                                    <Link className='group' href='/'>
                                        <p className='text-center py-3 rounded-lg text-gray-700 bg-white font-bold text-lg cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-50'>More Info</p>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='relative flex items-center justify-center w-full h-auto shadow-xl shadow-gray-400 rounded-xl p-4 group hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-[#565eef] to-[#709dff]'>
                        <Image className='rounded-xl group-hover:opacity-10' src={PropertyImg} alt='/'/>
                        <div className='hidden  group-hover:block absolute '>
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                                <div>
                                    <h3 className='text-2xl text-white tracking-wider text-center'>Property finder</h3>
                                    <p className='pb-4 pt-2 text-center text-white'>React Project</p>
                                    <Link className='group' href='/'>
                                        <p className='text-center py-3 rounded-lg text-gray-700 bg-white font-bold text-lg cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-50'>More Info</p>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='relative flex items-center justify-center w-full h-auto shadow-xl shadow-gray-400 rounded-xl p-4 group hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-[#565eef] to-[#709dff]'>
                        <Image className='rounded-xl group-hover:opacity-10' src={PropertyImg} alt='/'/>
                        <div className='hidden  group-hover:block absolute '>
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                                <div>
                                    <h3 className='text-2xl text-white tracking-wider text-center'>Property finder</h3>
                                    <p className='pb-4 pt-2 text-center text-white'>React Project</p>
                                    <Link className='group' href='/'>
                                        <p className='text-center py-3 rounded-lg text-gray-700 bg-white font-bold text-lg cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-50'>More Info</p>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Projects
```

the contact component:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link  from 'next/Link';
import ContactImage from '../public/assets/contact.jpg'
import {  AiOutlineMail } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { FaFacebook, FaGithub, FaLinkedinIn } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { BsFillPersonLinesFill } from 'react-icons/bs'
import { HiOutlineChevronDoubleUp } from 'react-icons/hi'

const Contact = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id='contact' className='w-full max-w-[1240px] mx-auto px-2 md:h-screen py-24 my-4'>

                <h3 className='text-xl tracking-widest uppercase text-[#5651e5]'>Contact</h3>
                <h1 className='mt-2 mb-6'>Get In Touch</h1>

                <div className='md:grid md:grid-cols-6 gap-4 h-5/6 w-full flex flex-col my-4 justify-center '>
                    <div className=' col-span-2 py-4 px-4 shadow-xl rounded-xl  shadow-gray-400 flex flex-col justify-between h-full'>
                        <div className='mt-2'>
                            <Image className='hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300 rounded-xl' src={ContactImage} alt='/' />
                            <h3>Mahmoud Ashraf</h3>
                            <p className='my-3'>Full Stack Web Developer</p>
                            <p>I am available for freelancer or full-time positions. contact me and lets talk.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className='text-center'>contact me on</p>
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center py-4 space-x-4">
                                <div className='rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer hover:scale-110 duration-500'>
                                    <FaLinkedinIn />
                                </div>
                                <div className='rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer hover:scale-110 duration-500'>
                                    <FaGithub />
                                </div>
                                <div className='rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer hover:scale-110 duration-500'>
                                    <AiOutlineMail />
                                </div>
                                <div className='rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer hover:scale-110 duration-500'>
                                    <FaFacebook />
                                </div>
                                <div className='rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-gray-400 p-3 cursor-pointer hover:scale-110 duration-500'>
                                    <BsFillPersonLinesFill />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-span-4 py-4 pt-10 md:px-12  shadow-xl rounded-xl  shadow-gray-400 flex justify-between flex-col'>
                        <div className='flex-col space-y-3'>
                            <div className='md:flex  justify-between md:space-x-3'>
                                <div className='flex flex-col w-full '>
                                    <label className='mb-1' htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" className='h-10 rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200' id='name' />
                                </div>
                                <div className='flex flex-col w-full '>
                                    <label className='mb-1' htmlFor="name">Phone</label>
                                    <input type="text" className='h-10 rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200' id='phone' />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='flex flex-col w-full '>
                                <label className='mb-1' htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" className='h-10 rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200' id='email' />
                            </div>
                            <div className='flex flex-col w-full '>
                                <label className='mb-1' htmlFor="subject">Subject</label>
                                <input type="text" className='h-10 rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200' id='subject' />
                            </div>
                            <div className='flex flex-col w-full '>
                                <label className='mb-1' htmlFor="message">Message</label>
                                <textarea type="text" className='h-36 rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200' id='message' />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full my-6 px-4'>
                            <button className='h-10 w-full md:w-3/4 hover:brightness-105'>Submit</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div className='flex flex-col  justify-center items-center my-10 cursor-pointer hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300'>
                        <Link href='/' alt='/'>
                            <HiOutlineChevronDoubleUp className='w-10 h-10  rounded-full shadow-lg my-4  shadow-gray-400 text-[#5651e5] p-2' />
                        </Link>
                    </div>


        </div>


    )
}

export default Contact
```

then this is the folder structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Dah.png)

Comment: I remove the import of both images and in the src, I added the path to them and and it worked but why It does not work when I import pics and pass them to the src attribute in the next/image component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research, i ended up solving and understanding it,

there are two ways to include a pic in your next application through next/image

- the first one is to import the image and then add it to your source attribute of next/image component.
- the second way if you are getting those images from an API or from any external URL in this case you have to configure image loader and you can read about this from here [enter link description here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader-configuration).